# Yahoo incorrect username or password?

Tags: python, yahoo-mail

I created yahoo email via web interface, have enabled pop3 access(set auto), but still get following error:

```
poplib.error_proto: -ERR [AUTH] (#MBR1212) Incorrect username or password.
```

My python script.

```
import poplib
oMailBox = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.mail.yahoo.com', port=995)
oMailBox.user(username)
oMailBox.pass_(password)
```

Comment: You used the full email address, not just the username?

Comment: yes, username and password are correct, i am sure

Comment: Here are the settings you need, other than that, I don't know what your problem could be -- https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN4724.html

Comment: @cricket_007 Server - pop.mail.yahoo.com, port-  995  SSL - Yes, i have this settings in my python script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried using your code on my Yahoo account, and I get the same error, but I also have a secondary email that tells me when unrecognized access happens on that account, in which case I see the below message.

Seems though you may have to also disable security on your account as well as enable POP3.

> Someone attempted to sign in to your Yahoo account ({ACCOUNT_NAME}) from an app that doesn't meet Yahoo's security standards. We blocked this sign in attempt, which was made on:
>
> {DATE} from {LOCATION}.
>
> If you were trying to sign in, then please take one of these actions:
>
> Option 1 (recommended): Use mail.yahoo.com or the Yahoo Mail app for
> Android and iOS to more securely access your account.
>
> Option 2 (not recommended): If you still want to use an app that uses
> less secure sign in to your Yahoo account:
>
> Click here: https://login.yahoo.com/account/security#other-apps
>
> Turn on "Allow apps that use less secure sign in"
>
> Go back to your existing email application and sign in to your Yahoo
> account again.
>
> Using apps that don't meet Yahoo's recommended security standards may
> leave your account more vulnerable or less secure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not enabled pop for the account? https://help.yahoo.com/kb/learn-enable-pop-in%C2%A0yahoo-mail-sln22038.html
or you don't have yahoo-plus account (http://www.freeemailtutorials.com/yahooMailTutorials/upgradeToYahooMailPlus.php)